# ¿Cómo hacer un select con linq o expresiones lambda de varias tablas C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, android-sqlite, linq-to-sql

Tengo varias tablas como se muestra en la imagen, y un query donde hago varios inner join para traerme los campos que requiero de cada tabla, lo tengo que hacer en C#, pero no puedo lograr hacer los inner join
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando con linq, pero no logro poder hacer un query que me haga inner joins como en sqlserver (ahora la bd está en sqlite, y requiero hacer en c# las consultas)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo como usar linq y no logro entender bien como funciona, se supone que donde está la variable T1 deberían salir las propiedades de la Entidad articulo, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: No te parece mejor crear un sp y llamarlo desde tu aplicación?

Comment: Hola Oscar, no coloques imágenes. Colócalo como texto directamente en la pregunta.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera  si la verdad a mi gusto es mejor un sp, con éstas consultas tediosas, pero apenas ando aprendiendo sqlite con android, y apenas ando investigando como funciona esa bd, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = database.Join(articulo,
ar => ar.campoT1, 
ac => ac.campoT2, 
(ar, ac) => new { T1 = ar, T2 = ac })
.Where(x => x.database.campo == parametro);
```

Ahora, la consulta consta de:

- `database`: es la tabla que corresponde al `From` en un `Select`.
- `articulo`: es la tabla con la que se realizará el `INNER JOIN`.
- `ar => ar.campoT1`/ `ac => ac.campoT2`: acá asignas un "*alias*" y accedes al campo que deseas comparar (si no aparece la sugerencia automática sólo escribe el campo).
- `(ar, ac) => new { T1 = ar, T2 = ac })`: La selección de los datos.
- `Where(x => x.database.campo == parametro)`: Cláusula `WHERE` si aplica para tu caso.

Aún así insisto en crear un `SP` y llamarlo desde tu aplicación cuando las consultas se ponen muy tediosas.

Espero te sirva :)

Answer (score -1):

en seudocodigo seria...
tabla1.joint(tabla2,vartabla1 => vartabla1.identificador, vartabla2 =>  vartabla2.identificador, ( vartabla1,  vartabla1) =>  vartabla1.campo que deseas retornar o vartabla1. campo que deseas retornar).where.....lo que deseas  filtrar de esa union de tablas...

nota: los procedimientos almacenados son algo del pasado, el negocio debe estar en el controlador no en el servidor pq asi este no se carga tanto y todoes muhco mas volatil en la propia aplicacion. Para mi el las basse de datos solo quedaran en el futuro para almacenar los datos pero la manipulacion de un scrud o funciones se haran en el controlador de la aplicacion asi aunque se caiga la conexion podras manupula ry opteenr tud resultados. en la parte visual

Comment: Podrias mirar [answer]? que aporta esta respuesta por sobre la respuesta aceptada? y ademas tu nota es mas una opinion que una realidad, ten cuidado con eso porque te pueden votar en contra, salvo que tengas fundamentos.